# Compiling given CGAL example

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gmp, cgal, mpfr

I'm trying to compile the first example presented in CGAL's Quadratic Programming document [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/QP_solver/QP_solver_2first_qp_8cpp-example.html).  I'm using Debian Jessie and installed CGAL via `sudo apt-get libcgal-dev` and verified that it's present in /usr/include, along with a few of its dependencies, e.g. boost, gmpxx.h, mpfr.h.  Per gmp's document [here](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#undef_ref2), I try to compile with: `g++ first_qp.cpp -lmpfr -lgmp`

It appears I get several linker errors below.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits<CGAL::Gmpz>::Integral_division::operator()(CGAL::Gmpz const&, CGAL::Gmpz const&) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL26Algebraic_structure_traitsINS_4GmpzEE17Integral_divisionclERKS1_S5_[_ZNK4CGAL26Algebraic_structure_traitsINS_4GmpzEE17Integral_divisionclERKS1_S5_]+0xac): undefined reference to `CGAL::postcondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Handle_for<CGAL::Gmpz_rep, std::allocator<CGAL::Gmpz_rep> >::Handle_for(CGAL::Handle_for<CGAL::Gmpz_rep, std::allocator<CGAL::Gmpz_rep> > const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL10Handle_forINS_8Gmpz_repESaIS1_EEC2ERKS3_[_ZN4CGAL10Handle_forINS_8Gmpz_repESaIS1_EEC5ERKS3_]+0x50): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>::Quadratic_program(CGAL::Sign, bool, int, bool, int)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiEC2ENS_4SignEbibi[_ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiEC5ENS_4SignEbibi]+0x190): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>::set_a(int, int, int const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_aEiiRKi[_ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_aEiiRKi]+0x41): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_aEiiRKi[_ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_aEiiRKi]+0x70): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>::set_b(int, int const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_bEiRKi[_ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_bEiRKi]+0x3e): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o:first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_uEibRKi[_ZN4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5set_uEibRKi]+0x43): more undefined references to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)' follow
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::set_pricing_strategy(CGAL::Quadratic_program_pricing_strategy)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE]+0xee): undefined reference to `CGAL::default_random'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE]+0x140): undefined reference to `CGAL::default_random'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE20set_pricing_strategyENS_34Quadratic_program_pricing_strategyE]+0x1d2): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::set(CGAL::Quadratic_program<int> const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE3setERKS2_[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE3setERKS2_]+0x55): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE3setERKS2_[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE3setERKS2_]+0x90): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::init()':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE4initEv[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE4initEv]+0x107): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::solve()':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE5solveEv[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE5solveEv]+0x40): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o:first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5get_rEv[_ZNK4CGAL17Quadratic_programIiE5get_rEv]+0x3f): more undefined references to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)' follow
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::Gmpz>::Quotient<CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::Gmpz>(CGAL::Gmpz const&, CGAL::Gmpz const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL8QuotientINS_4GmpzEEC2IS1_S1_EERKT_RKT0_[_ZN4CGAL8QuotientINS_4GmpzEEC5IS1_S1_EERKT_RKT0_]+0x88): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<CGAL::Gmpz>::infeasibility_certificate_begin() const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31infeasibility_certificate_beginEv[_ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31infeasibility_certificate_beginEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31infeasibility_certificate_beginEv[_ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31infeasibility_certificate_beginEv]+0x7b): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<CGAL::Gmpz>::unboundedness_certificate_begin() const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31unboundedness_certificate_beginEv[_ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31unboundedness_certificate_beginEv]+0x42): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31unboundedness_certificate_beginEv[_ZNK4CGAL26Quadratic_program_solutionINS_4GmpzEE31unboundedness_certificate_beginEv]+0x7b): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::init_x_O_v_i()':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE12init_x_O_v_iEv[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE12init_x_O_v_iEv]+0x1d5): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o:first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE3setEiii[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE3setEiii]+0x43): more undefined references to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)' follow
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Map_with_default<std::map<unsigned long, CGAL::Sign, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CGAL::Sign> > > >::operator()(unsigned long) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImNS_4SignESt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmS2_EEEEclEm[_ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImNS_4SignESt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmS2_EEEEclEm]+0x40): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Map_with_default<std::map<unsigned long, int, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> > > >::operator()(unsigned long) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImiSt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmiEEEEclEm[_ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImiSt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmiEEEEclEm]+0x40): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Map_with_default<std::map<unsigned long, bool, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, bool> > > >::operator()(unsigned long) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImbSt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmbEEEEclEm[_ZNK4CGAL16Map_with_defaultISt3mapImbSt4lessImESaISt4pairIKmbEEEEclEm]+0x40): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_basis_inverse<CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> >::ensure_physical_row(unsigned int)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj]+0x4f): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj]+0x102): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj]+0x198): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE19ensure_physical_rowEj]+0x239): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::original_variable_value_under_bounds(int) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36original_variable_value_under_boundsEi[_ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36original_variable_value_under_boundsEi]+0x6c): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o:first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36original_variable_value_under_boundsEi[_ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36original_variable_value_under_boundsEi]+0x163): more undefined references to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)' follow
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::Gmpz>::operator/=(CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::Gmpz> const&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL8QuotientINS_4GmpzEEdVERKS2_[_ZN4CGAL8QuotientINS_4GmpzEEdVERKS2_]+0x4d): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::replace_variable(CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE16replace_variableES7_[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE16replace_variableES7_]+0x18c): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::z_replace_variable_slack_by_original()':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36z_replace_variable_slack_by_originalEv[_ZN4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE36z_replace_variable_slack_by_originalEv]+0xeb): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `void CGAL::QP_basis_inverse<CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> >::enter_original_leave_original<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Gmpz*, std::vector<CGAL::Gmpz, std::allocator<CGAL::Gmpz> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Gmpz*, std::vector<CGAL::Gmpz, std::allocator<CGAL::Gmpz> > >, unsigned int)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j]+0x6d): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j]+0xa7): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE29enter_original_leave_originalIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEEEEvT_j]+0x49c): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o:first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE26enter_original_leave_slackIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEESC_EEvT_T0_[_ZN4CGAL16QP_basis_inverseINS_4GmpzENS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEEE26enter_original_leave_slackIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_St6vectorIS1_SaIS1_EEEESC_EEvT_T0_]+0x6e): more undefined references to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)' follow
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP__partial_base<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::activating(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP__partial_baseINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE10activatingERN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEE[_ZN4CGAL16QP__partial_baseINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE10activatingERN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP__partial_base<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::entering_basis(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZN4CGAL16QP__partial_baseINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE14entering_basisEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEE[_ZN4CGAL16QP__partial_baseINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE14entering_basisEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::nonbasic_original_variable_bound_index(int) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE38nonbasic_original_variable_bound_indexEi[_ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE38nonbasic_original_variable_bound_indexEi]+0x80): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE38nonbasic_original_variable_bound_indexEi[_ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE38nonbasic_original_variable_bound_indexEi]+0xd1): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
/tmp/ccPeDUda.o: In function `CGAL::QP_solver<CGAL::Quadratic_program<int>, CGAL::Gmpz, CGAL::QP_solver_impl::QP_tags<CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> > >::state_of_zero_nonbasic_variable(int) const':
first_qp.cpp:(.text._ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE31state_of_zero_nonbasic_variableEi[_ZNK4CGAL9QP_solverINS_17Quadratic_programIiEENS_4GmpzENS_14QP_solver_impl7QP_tagsINS_11Boolean_tagILb0EEES7_EEE31state_of_zero_nonbasic_variableEi]+0xc1): undefined reference to `CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)'
```

Comment: It looks as if _compiling_ the code worked OK: the errors are _linker_ errors. That implies you are missing a library while linking. I don't know the name of the library CGAL uses but assuming it is named `libcgal.a` (or `libcgal.so`) and installed in a location searched by default you'd use `g++ first_qp.cpp -lcgal -lmpfr -lgmp`

Comment: At least `-lCGAL -lCGAL_Core`  would be required.

Comment: /usr/share/doc/libcgal-demo/README.Debian suggests you should use cmake.

Comment: @MatsPetersson why `-lCGAL_Core`? I don't see any missing symbol error about `CORE::something`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmake to resolve these types of conflicts. ex:

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists -s executable 
cmake . 
make
```

The example mentioned achieved success.